# High CPU caused by system interrupts

Tags: performance-monitoring, interrupts, xperf, dpc

We have a three day old Idacentre A740 AIO PC. (windows 8.1 pro)

The system is up-to-date.

After we start the PC and "do notthing" the system interrupts taken 40% CPU time approximately.

Tried to find what causing we used xperf and wpm. I need help to understand the output of xpref.

I think the problem with the HAL.dll (or the ACPI.sys?) Any suggestion, how to solve this?

[image: http://pasteboard.co/yib61ED.jpg]

[image: http://pasteboard.co/yi8Mjfl.jpg]

[image: http://pasteboard.co/ymVFWwC.jpg]

Thank you

Comment: Try to look for missing drivers or update your drivers.
But high CPU usage can be caused by many things.
Perhaps installing updates in the background, trigged then the machine is idle.

Comment: -The CPU intterrupts constantly high...
- Drivers up to date
- hal.dll, ntoskern.exe, acpi.sys...this three which i can see...

Comment: This definitely smells like a driver problem. Did you reinstall the system with a clean image? If so you might need to install the motherboard specific drivers. Acpi.sys and Hal.DLL are both generic roots of the device management hierarchy and I suspect the device specific driver would put that device into a more efficient transfer mode.

Comment: Yes. We install a new Windows 8.1 Pro - and after than we use the factroy driver disk. Than we use the recovery partition to install all factory application. Than made a windows update, intel update, nvidia update...

Comment: please share the ETL (compressed as zip to reduce the size) on OneDrive and post the share link here.